# python3 - Flask - Issue printing accents - encoding problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, character-encoding, apache2

I have a Flask app, in Python3.10, running in "prod" via Apache2.

My app is not able to handle and print accents at all, and this is driving me crazy! :|

What i need, is my app being able to print a string with accent (é) on apache2 error log file (error.log) and being able to concatenate it to a an other string for a Greatfunction.

Basically, my __**init __** look like this:

```
def flask_app():
  @app.route('/api')
  def api():
    print(locale.getpreferredencoding()) #print in apache2 error log: ANSI_X3.4-1968
    print(sys.stdout.encoding) #print in apache2 error log: utf-8
    a = "Témaki"
    print(a) #print in apache2 error log: T\xc3\xa9maki
    b = "dostuff " + a
    print(b) #print in apache2 error log: dostuff T\xc3\xa9maki
    GreatFunction(b) #Fail because the accent is not properly given in string. (enoding error)
```

i tried a LOT of things on internet (even chatgpt), But nothing worked! I probably don't understand how encoding is handled by Flask.

Of course, if i try the same thing on a TTY python shell prompt directly: Everything works great and accents are properly displayed.

So please, help me to make my python (Flask) able to print and manage accents.

Thanks.

I tried: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`, with no success.

I tried:

```
print("Témaki".encode('utf-8')) #print: b'T\\xc3\\xa9maki'
print("Témaki".encode('latin-1')) #print b'T\\xe9maki'
print("Témaki".encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8')) #print T\xc3\xa9maki
print("Témaki".encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')) #ERROR: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

with no success.

I tried:

```
def getpreferredencoding(do_setlocale = True):
   return "utf-8"
locale.getpreferredencoding = getpreferredencoding
```

with no success.